# I want to generate current epoch time in scala

Tags: scala, time

I am trying to generate a new epoch timestamp(eg 1435655706000) in scala.
I've used the below function but got time format.

```
Val timestamp: Timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

Comment: it is better to use the `java.time.Instant.now.toEpochMilli` like the answer below. But in case you want to keep using Timestamp you have to use to full package `java.sql.Timestamp` when declaring this class -> `val timestamp: java.sql.Timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())`.

Comment: @Felipe, that is the second answer in the attached link :) You can upvote it

Answer (score 7):

Use `java.time` instances when you work with time

```
java.time.Instant.now.toEpochMilli
```